# CSS Keep accordion menu open when changing page

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

I have a HTML/CSS page on the go right now where in the middle is an image map. On the left hand side I have an accordion menu in CSS. The idea is that when a user opens the accordion menu, when they change to the next page by clicking on a part of the image, the accordion will stay open to that spot. This is for training. So the instructions are on the left hand side and they can do it on the image map in the middle. Here's the CSS I have for the accordion:

Here is the stylesheet:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
div.img {
    float: right; 
    Border: 1px solid white; 
}

.right {
    margin: auto;
}

.accordion {
width: 350px;
box-shadow:
    0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(12,12,12,0.3),
    0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
Float: left;
Position: fixed;
}
.accordion label {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 5px 20px;
position: Relative;
display: block;
height: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 33px;
font-size: 19px;
background: #3333ff;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.accordion name:hover {
background: #F3FF3F3;
}
.accordion input + label {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion input:checked + label,
.accordion input:checked + label:hover {
    background: #ff2000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow:
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3),
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.accordion input {
    display: none;
}
.accordion .content {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion .content p {
    font-family: "Arial"; 
    color: #777;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.accordion input:checked ~ .content {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion input:checked ~ .content.ac-medium {
height: 195px;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<p style="color:white;float:top-left;font-family:Arial;font-size:25px;margin-bottom:0px;">Title</p>
<p style="color:white;float:top-left;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;"> Subtitle</p>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
</head>
<br>
<br>
 <div class="container">
<div class="accordion">
<div>
        <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-1">Description</label>
<div class="content ac-medium">
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
        <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-2">Description</label>
<div class="content ac-medium">
</div>
</div>
<div>
        <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-3">Description</label>
    <div class="content ac-medium">

</div>
</div>
<div>
        <input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="ac-4">Description</label>
<div class="content ac-medium">
Description
</div>
</div>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-5" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-5">Category</label>
    <div class="content ac-medium">
    Description
    </div>
    <div>
            <input id="ac-6" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="ac-6">Category</label>
    <div class="content ac-medium">
    Description
    </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="img">
<div class="right">
<img src="CWS.png" width="1200" height="900" usemap="#CWS" /> 
</div>
</div>
<map name="CWS">
</map>
</html>
```

If this can be kept in CSS and HTML, that would be great as I'm not familiar with any other languages. Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT:
So after scouring the internet I've found something that seems promising. I'm not a java guy but I figured I'd give this a shot:

```
   // Initialize Stop Var
    var stop = false;

// When the Drop Down is Clicked, Set Stop Var to True
$("#drop-down").click(function(event) { stop=true; });

// Prevent Accordion Close if Stop Var Set
$("#accordion").click(function(event) {
    if (stop) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        stop = false;
    }
});
```

I guess my question is, how can I implement the above java to work with my code. I'm not sure what values to change the "drop-down" and "accordion" to (if I even have to change accordion)

This will be stand alone, so there won't be any server side code.

Edit2:

Looks like I might not be allowed to use java.... is there a way to not have the menu refresh when changing screens?

Comment: You'd need Javascript to do that...it's not possible with HTML/CSS alone.

Comment: You refer to image map. You mean one line this? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: Yes. Just like that one.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm not putting any effort into this, but if I need java, could someone give me a headstart as to what the code would be? I don't know java.

Comment: If your redirecting the user to a new page, there's a new request to the server, this means that its not possible without some server side programming language. **Are you using one ?** If so, please specify to see if we can help.

Comment: Yes it is being redirected to a new page. As far as how this will be hosted, that is tbd. 

There is a work around that I can think of. I'm sure it's just a simple change and would work for what I need it to do. How could I have one of the headings open automatically when a new page is opened. That way, it will simulate staying open.

Comment: I should add: I am a noob. I'm learning CSS as I go.

Comment: If java would do the trick, I would not be opposed to that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to tell the page that something needs to be set/changed.

HTML: you create all pages the user can click and add the CSS needed to display the desired result. Fx. www.example.com/page1.html, page2.html ect. Then you set the display/hide specifically in the accordion.

Javascript: You set a cookie with the desired option/selection and then read that cookie on page load. This is not perfect as you may experience a flicker while page is being rendered.

Serverside: fx. using PHP you make your link like this: www.example.com/?accordion=1, ?accordion=2 ect. Then you check for this URL parameter and set's the CSS accordingly.

Comment: There won't be any server side. This will be stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm going in a different direction with this project. Framesets are what I'll be using. Thanks everyone for your help!